# Why does my associative array turn into an indexed one halfway through? and then changes back to an associative one?

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I'm writing this code that changes an indexed array to an associative array.  It works for all the states I've checked, except california. For california, its an associative array for a little while, and then it changes to an indexed array out of nowhere and back to an associative one at the end.  When I echo the individual indexes, I get the values I'm looking to use in the associative array so I'm not sure why it doesn't stick.  Can anyone help?

```
$ids_file = file_get_contents("http://waterdata.usgs.gov/ca/nwis/current?index_pmcode_STATION_NM=1&index_pmcode_DATETIME=2&index_pmcode_72019=72&index_pmcode_00065=261&index_pmcode_00060=191&group_key=NONE&format=sitefile_output&sitefile_output_format=rdb&column_name=agency_cd&column_name=site_no&column_name=station_nm&column_name=dec_lat_va&column_name=dec_long_va&column_name=coord_acy_cd&column_name=dec_coord_datum_cd&column_name=alt_va&column_name=alt_acy_va&column_name=alt_datum_cd&sort_key_2=site_no&html_table_group_key=NONE&rdb_compression=file&list_of_search_criteria=realtime_parameter_selection");
$gages = explode("\t",$ids_file);

//this provides the randomized list of gages to pick from

for($i=19;$i<count($gages);$i=$i+9){
    $gagenew = array($gages[$i]=>$gages[$i+1]);
    $gagenum = array_merge($gagenum,$gagenew);
}
```

this is a small sample of what I get when I echo `$gagenum`

```
[09526200] => YPSILANTI CANAL NEAR WINTERHAVEN, CA 
[09527590] => COACHELLA CANAL ABV ALL-AMERICAN CANAL DIV 
[09527594] => COACHELLA CANAL NEAR NILAND, CA 
[09527597] => COACHELLA CANAL NEAR DESERT BEACH, CA 
[09527700] => ALL-AMERICAN CANAL BELOW DROP 2 RESERVOIR OUTLET 
[09530000] => RESERVATION MAIN DRAIN NO. 4 NEAR YUMA, AZ 
[09530500] => DRAIN 8-B NEAR WINTERHAVEN, CA 
[0] => BOREHOLE SPG CHANNEL NR TECOPA HOT SPGS, CA 
[1] => AMARGOSA RV AT TECOPA, CA 
[2] => AMARGOSA RV ABV CHINA RANCH WASH NR TECOPA, CA 
[3] => WILLOW CK AT CHINA RANCH, CA 
[4] => SALT C NR MECCA 
[5] => ALAMO R NR NILAND CA 
[6] => NEW R AT INTERNATIONAL BOUNDARY AT CALEXICO CA 
[7] => NEW R NR WESTMORLAND CA 
[8] => SNOW C NR WHITE WATER CA 
[9] => FALLS C NR WHITE WATER CA 
[10] => WHITEWATER R A WINDY POINT MAIN CHANNEL CA 
[11] => WHITEWATER R A WINDY POINT OVERFLOW CHANNEL CA
```

see where is it changes to an indexed array out of nowhere?

Comment: where is `$number` coming from? what value is it?

Comment: What is `$gagenum` supposed to be?

Comment: @ChristopherMorrissey oops...that is a mistake...Let me edit that

Comment: @Dachi $gagenum is supposed to be an associative array of the gage number and the gage title.  The first 7 outputs of the sample are correct.

Comment: use var_dump instead of print_r to better understand this. numbers and strings as keys mixed you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem comes from the behavior that naturally occurs in `array_merge()`:

> Merges the elements of one or more arrays together so that the values of one are appended to the end of the previous one. It returns the resulting array.
>
> If the input arrays have the same string keys, then the later value for that key will overwrite the previous one. If, however, the arrays contain numeric keys, the later value will not overwrite the original value, but will be appended.
>
> **Values in the input array with numeric keys will be renumbered with incrementing keys starting from zero in the result array.**

[PHP array_merge() Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)

You could try declaring all your keys as strings.

**Edit**

Oddly enough, my testing can't get it to behave. Even stranger than that, I found a simpler method of joining arrays that I never even considered.

```
//Replace array_merge() with this
$gagenum += $gagenew;
```

When you `print_r($gagenum)` it should be the two arrays joined with the keys they had. You could either leave it at that or use the result for a `var_dump($gagenum)` and debug it.

**Experimentation**

Further tests with the differences between `array_merge()` and the concatenation method `$array1 + $array2` should help give a better understanding of the difference.

```
<?php
$int1 = array( 2 => 'george', 3 => 'sam', 4 => 'bob' );
$int2 = array( 0 => 'sue', 1 => 'debbie', 2 => 'sally' );
$str1 = array( 'one' => 'ken', 'two' => 'tom', 'three' => 'phil' );
$str2 = array( 'three' => 'jenny', 'four' => 'alice', 'five' => 'jan' );

$mergeii = array_merge( $int1, $int2 );
$mergeis = array_merge( $int1, $str1 );
$mergesi = array_merge( $str1, $int1 );
$mergess = array_merge( $str1, $str2 );
$concatii = $int1 + $int2;
$concatis = $int1 + $str1;
$concatsi = $str1 + $int1;
$concatss = $str1 + $str2;

// Merge Int/Int - Numeric Keys Reassigned Starting From [0], with $int1 first. No Overwrites.
echo "Merge Int/Int:\r\n"; print_r($mergeii);

// Merge Int/Str - Numeric Keys Reassigned Starting From [0], $int1 first. No Overwrites.
echo "\r\nMerge Int/Str:\r\n"; print_r($mergeis);

// Merge Str/Int - Numeric Keys Reassigned Again, $str1 first. No Overwrites.
echo "\r\nMerge Str/Int:\r\n"; print_r($mergesi);

// Merge Str/Str - No Numeric Keys. Value of Key 'Three' overwritten with $str2 value. Bye bye, 'phil'.
echo "\r\nMerge Str/Str:\r\n"; print_r($mergess);

// Concatenate Int/Int - Numeric Keys Preserved. Value of Key (int)2 from $int1 Preserved, 'sally' lost.
echo "\r\nConcatenate Int/Int:\r\n"; print_r($concatii);

// Concatenate Int/Str - Expected results, All Key/Value Pairs Preserved
echo "\r\nConcatenate Int/Str:\r\n"; print_r($concatis);

// Concatenate Str/Int - Expected results, All Key/value Pairs Preserved
echo "\r\nConcatenate Str/Int:\r\n"; print_r($concatsi);

// Concatenate Str/Str - Expected results, Value of Key (str)'three' from $int1 Preserved, 'jenny' lost.
echo "\r\nConcatenate Str/Str:\r\n"; print_r($concatss);
?>
```

So `array_merge()` prioritizes the second argument over the first, and the concatenation method prioritizes the first over the second. `array_merge()` for some reason still treats numeral-like strings as int, even if explicitly declared. This was by changing the line to:

```
$int1 = array( (string)'2' => 'george', (string)'3' => 'sam', (string)'4' => 'bob' );
```

`var_dump($int1)` correctly shows the keys as strings before merging, yet still reassigns the keys numerically. Bug perhaps?

**Which one is *Faster***

On to the performance test! Tests were done without altering the original array, was tested using 8 for loops with this format:

```
$start1 = microtime(true);
for( $x = 0; $x < 100000; ++$x)
{
    $merged = array_merge($int1, $int2);
}
$end1 = microtime(true);
```

- **Array Merge Function** Average time was anywhere between 0.15 - 0.19 seconds, with $int1/$int2 usually being the lowest by -0.01, where $str1/$str2 was usually +0.02 seconds. $str1/$int1 and $int1/$str1 flip-flopped between the middle average 0.16-0.17.
- **Concatenation Method** Average time was anywhere between 0.05 - 0.07. Once again, $int1/$int2 was the leader by -0.01 second. $str1/$str2 was also +0.02 seconds longer typically.

So the concatenation method is definitely a better method, especially if you want to preserve array keys. Use `array_merge()` when you want to keep all values, but want to restructure two different `int` arrays into a sequential array for scripts that could use a good `for` loop.

Comment: Yes, I thought that this might have been an issue. I tried using `strval` to change the numbers to strings but maybe I didn't do it right...I'll try that again.

Comment: Totally spaced, found the += method right on the array_merge php manual comments.

Comment: weird!  I can't believe it was that simple!  and here I was ripping my hair out analyzing every aspect of these arrays!  Thanks!

Comment: Not sure on the optimization aspect of it, but I'll probably be using it in the future myself, and perhaps going back to old projects if it'll make my code cleaner :D

Comment: Now I'm sure on the optimization aspect :)

Comment: You cannot force numeric keys to be strings in PHP - it specifically coerces them to integers. This is to avoid surprising users by `$foo[ $_GET['id'] ]` referring to a different element from `$foo[ intval($_GET['id']) ]`, but still having optimised "non-associative" arrays (e.g. the return from `array_values`).

Comment: If you don't explicitly define it, PHP assumes you want an int. However, you can `array( (string)1 => 'My Key Is A String!' );`.